# Вопрос по async/await

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Пытаюсь перелезть с промисов на сабж, не получается:

```
async function vkApiCall(method, params) {
  params['access_token'] = params['access_token'] || VK_APP_TOKEN;
  const params = Object.keys(params).map(k => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[k])}`).join('&');
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.vk.com/method/${method}?${params}`);
  return await response.json();
}

function loadVkCities() {
  const data = await vkApiCall('database.getCitiesById', {
    country_id: 1,
    need_all: 1
  });
  console.log(data);
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
const data = await vkApiCall('database.getCitiesById', {
                   ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:576:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:653:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы использовать await функция должна быть объявлена с async:

```
async function loadVkCities() {
  const data = await vkApiCall('database.getCitiesById', {
    country_id: 1,
    need_all: 1
  });
  console.log(data);
}
```

и при возврате json await лишний. Тут ждать нечего

```
return await response.json();
```

можно просто вернуть значение

```
return response.json();
```